# symfony 2 : customized manyToMany relationship while update an added element

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a customized many to many relationship, (one to many and many to one) for entities : Formation, Pjs , I created manually the new relation table nammed FormationPjs to which I added a new field, I think I have the problem in the form one of the forms because when I create a new  Formation it goes successfully, but when I checked the relationship table I found its empty, none was added to it, this is the code of the entities :

```
class Formation
    {
    /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\User\UserBundle\Entity\FormationPjs", mappedBy="formation",cascade={"persist"})
         * 
         */
        private $justifs;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->justifs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add justif
     *
     * @param \User\UserBundle\Entity\FormationPjs $justif
     * @return Formation
     */
    public function addJustif(\User\UserBundle\Entity\FormationPjs $justif)
    {
        $this->justifs[] = $justif;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove justif
     *
     * @param \User\UserBundle\Entity\FormationPjs $justif
     */
    public function removeJustif(\User\UserBundle\Entity\FormationPjs $justif)
    {
        $this->justifs->removeElement($justif);
    }

    /**
     * Get justif
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getJustifs()
    {
        return $this->justifs;
    }
}


class FormationPjs
{
/** 
 * 
 * @var \Client\ClientBundle\Entity\Pjs
 * 
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Client\ClientBundle\Entity\Pjs" , cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idPjs", referencedColumnName="idpjs")
*/
private $pjs;

/** 
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Formation", inversedBy="justif")
 */
private $formation;
 /**
 * Set formation
 *
 * @param \User\UserBundle\Entity\Formation $formation
 * @return Formation_Pjs
 */
public function setFormation(\User\UserBundle\Entity\Formation $formation)
{
    $this->formation = $formation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get formation
 *
 * @return \User\UserBundle\Entity\Formation 
 */
public function getFormation()
{
    return $this->formation;
}

/**
 * Set pjs
 *
 * @param \Client\ClientBundle\Entity\Pjs $pjs
 * @return Formation_Pjs
 */
public function setPjs(\Client\ClientBundle\Entity\Pjs $pjs )
{
    $this->pjs = $pjs;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get pjs
 *
 * @return \Client\ClientBundle\Entity\Pjs 
 */
public function getPjs()
{
    return $this->pjs;
}
}
```

and the code of the forms:

```
    class FormationType extends AbstractType {

     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('justifs', 'collection', array('required' => false,'type'         => new FormationPjsType(),
                                            'allow_add'    => true,
                                            'prototype' => true,
                                            'allow_delete' => true,
                                            'by_reference' => true
                ))

    class FormationPjsType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('libelle','text', array('required' => false, 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
            ->add('pjs', new PjsType())
        ;
    }
```

and the error is :

> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php
>   line 1592
>
> at ErrorHandler ->handle ('8', 'Undefined index: id', 'C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php',
>   '1592', array('assoc' => array('fieldName' => 'justifs', 'mappedBy' =>
>   'formation', 'targetEntity' => 'User\UserBundle\Entity\FormationPjs',
>   'cascade' => array('persist'), 'orphanRemoval' => false, 'fetch' =>
>   '2', 'type' => '4', 'inversedBy' => null, 'isOwningSide' => false,
>   'sourceEntity' => 'User\UserBundle\Entity\Formation',
>   'isCascadeRemove' => false, 'isCascadePersist' => true,
>   'isCascadeRefresh' => false, 'isCascadeMerge' => false,
>   'isCascadeDetach' => false), 'sourceEntity' => object(Formation),
>   'offset' => null, 'limit' => null, 'criteria' => array(),
>   'owningAssoc' => array('fieldName' => 'formation', 'joinColumns' =>
>   array(array('name' => 'formation_id', 'referencedColumnName' =>
>   'id')), 'cascade' => array(), 'inversedBy' => 'justif', 'targetEntity'
>   => 'User\UserBundle\Entity\Formation', 'fetch' => '2', 'type' => '2', 'mappedBy' => null, 'isOwningSide' => true, 'sourceEntity' =>
>   'User\UserBundle\Entity\FormationPjs', 'isCascadeRemove' => false,
>   'isCascadePersist' => false, 'isCascadeRefresh' => false,
>   'isCascadeMerge' => false, 'isCascadeDetach' => false,
>   'sourceToTargetKeyColumns' => array('formation_id' => 'id'),
>   'joinColumnFieldNames' => array('formation_id' => 'formation_id'),
>   'targetToSourceKeyColumns' => array('id' => 'formation_id'),
>   'orphanRemoval' => false), 'sourceClass' => object(ClassMetadata),
>   'tableAlias' => 't0', 'sourceKeyColumn' => 'id', 'targetKeyColumn' =>
>   'formation_id'))  in
>   C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php
>   at line 1592   +  at BasicEntityPersister ->getOneToManyStatement
>   (array('fieldName' => 'justifs', 'mappedBy' => 'formation',
>   'targetEntity' => 'User\UserBundle\Entity\FormationPjs', 'cascade' =>
>   array('persist'), 'orphanRemoval' => false, 'fetch' => '2', 'type' =>
>   '4', 'inversedBy' => null, 'isOwningSide' => false, 'sourceEntity' =>
>   'User\UserBundle\Entity\Formation', 'isCascadeRemove' => false,
>   'isCascadePersist' => true, 'isCascadeRefresh' => false,
>   'isCascadeMerge' => false, 'isCascadeDetach' => false),
>   object(Formation))  in
>   C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php
>   at line 1558   +  at BasicEntityPersister ->loadOneToManyCollection
>   (array('fieldName' => 'justifs', 'mappedBy' => 'formation',
>   'targetEntity' => 'User\UserBundle\Entity\FormationPjs', 'cascade' =>
>   array('persist'), 'orphanRemoval' => false, 'fetch' => '2', 'type' =>
>   '4', 'inversedBy' => null, 'isOwningSide' => false, 'sourceEntity' =>
>   'User\UserBundle\Entity\Formation', 'isCascadeRemove' => false,
>   'isCascadePersist' => true, 'isCascadeRefresh' => false,
>   'isCascadeMerge' => false, 'isCascadeDetach' => false),
>   object(Formation), object(PersistentCollection))  in
>   C:\wamp\www\GESTIBAT0.1\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php
>   at line 2704   +

plz I need help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should try to use entity type not collection, cause collection is for other forms, and not for entities, so in the option array for the type key you should pass in a formtype, and not an entity representation

Comment: thanks for your comment, I have the entity Formation form calls the FormationPjs form and the last one calls the Pjs form, what could I do ?

Comment: thanks for your comment, I have the entity Formation form calls the FormationPjs form and the last one calls the Pjs form, and by adding a new formation a new formationPjs must be added and Pjs as well , what should I do ?